# How to get k2 item and category to use different templates?

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, cms

This is a very old problem, I asked it before but never got a satisfying answer.

By default, on a "k2 category" page, when you click one of the items, the "k2 item" page will keep using the current template that "k2 category" page is using. However, in most occasions, I'd want it to use its own template.

There are some workarounds, like setting hidden menu items for each k2 items(huge workload), or hacking some K2 file to change the way it builds item link(too rude). So my question was and still is, has there been any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The option to select different template was direct relation with menu item. 
Than, if you dont want chage codes, i really belive you need hide menu itens and set different template there.